# Selenium does not load site at all

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I can't load a site. Selenium starts when I run my code (aka the specified browser opens - in this case Firefox) but absolutely nothing happens! I just have a blank browser. My code is as follows:

```
    from selenium import webdriver

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('http://isol.alachuaclerk.org/RealEstate/SearchEntry.aspx')
```

I can load the site manually in Firefox but Selenium/geckodriver can't. What's going on?!

Comment: Check whether the site is reachable in debug console? Also you can view the log of webdriver(for firefox, it's geckodriver) to get more details.

Comment: @artificerpi Thanks for the suggestion. However, there is nothing there either. Nothing in the console log, no network activity (not even an error code like 404 to show me it tried to connect), just nothing.

Comment: No output log for geckodriver?

Comment: Zero output. Selenium just returns with a blank browser.

Answer (score 0):

I still do not know what the issue is. Not really a fix but rolling back a few geckodriver versions solved this. Why the latest geckodriver doesn't load this site but an older version does is beyond me.